# How can I use xmlns in custom tags?

Tags: jsp, jsf

```
xmlns:bs ="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
```

Then designing for custom tag and saving with menu.tag

```
<div class=xyz>
....
```

Usually xmlns is used with html tag . Here I cannot use HTML tag in custom tags so how to use bs?

Comment: Did you try using it on the first tag in the xhtml file? If not, please do... that 'just' works

Comment: Custom JSP or JSF tag?

Comment: Since you added [jsp] tag, this question introduced confusing ambiguity. JSP is not a XML based view technology. XML namespaces like `xmlns:foo` would never work in JSP. Moreover, as JSP is deprecated since JSF 2.0, all JSF 2.x compatible component libraries like BootsFaces doesn't support JSP at all. Are you really using JSP (JSF pages with `.jsp` extension) or did you mistakenly tag it while you're *actually* using Facelets (JSF pages with `.xhtml` extension)? Facelets as being XML based view technology of course just supports XML namespaces. Please edit and clarify.

Comment: I am using JSF 2.0 only and saving it .jsp extension. In normal pages i am using <html xmlns:bs ="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"> </html> but right now i want to create custom tags so i cannot use html tag. I have coded like this <%@ tag language="java" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<div class="topnavbar" xmlns:bs="http://bootsfaces.net/ui">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">. Is it correct way to write ?